# Select all from Table A where id isnt in pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a category table and a pivot table which determines the child categories. I wanted to use eloquent to select all the top level categories (categories that do not have a parent). I did want to do it with one eloquent query but haven't managed to get my head around it.

Database Structure

```
library_categories
    id
    title
    slug

library_category_relationships
    id
    parent_id
    category_id
```

Model

```
class LibraryCategory extends \Eloquent {

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('LibraryCategory', 'library_category_relationships', 'parent_id', 'category_id');
    }

    public function parents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('LibraryCategory', 'library_category_relationships', 'category_id', 'parent_id');
    }

}
```

Current Query (Located in a repository method)

```
$relationshipIds = DB::table('library_category_relationships')
                            ->select('category_id')
                            ->distinct()
                            ->get();

// Merge with id of 0 to avoid error in the next query if no relationships are found
$relationshipIds = array_merge([0], array_fetch($relationshipIds, 'category_id'));

return $this->model
            ->with($this->relationships)
            ->orderBy($orderBy, $sort)
            ->whereNotIn('id', $relationshipIds)
            ->paginate(Config::get('intranet.pagination.per_page'));
```

As you can see in the first half I fetch all the unique category ids from the pivot table that are children and in the second query I fetch the categories from that are not in the previous results.

Is it possible to some how include this in just one query? I would like to keep this contained within eloquent.

Thanks

Comment: Generally it's SELECT a LEFT JOIN b ON (condition) WHERE b.id IS NULL

Comment: Why do you store the relationship in a second table? Can't you just add a `parent_id` to the `library_categories` table? This would make this much easier, you could just search for the categories with `parent_id = null`.

Comment: The decision to have a pivot table is because a category can have multiple parents